# estimate ram usage for my vps

Tags: centos, vps, memory

I'm gonna get a new vps, I'm gonna probably need 1 TB of bandwidth, around 20GB - 25GB of disk space - it's a php-mysql website, the php script itself is about 300kb but there will be many videos on the site.

I'm not gonna install a cpanel or any hosting panel coz they use a lot of ram, I'm gonna have a centos vps, with ffmpeg, lamp, BIND, vsftpd, and some libraries which may be needed with ffmpeg

how to estimate the ram usage so i can get the best vps for my needs? I already know from where I'm gonna get my [vps](http://chvps.com/), I don't know which one to choose yet

and I would like you to teach me how to estimate ram usage. Thank you in advance

one more thing, is it good if i choose Lighttpd or Nginx instead of apache? coz apache uses a lot of ram, but then do i need to modify my script or not to work with them?

Comment: What exactly are you going to be doing with ffmpeg?  Manipulating a media file is almost certainly going to be resource intensive.

Comment: FYI.  The easiest way to estimate it, is to try it on a test box and see what happens.

Comment: @Zoredache ffmpeg is ffmpeg lol :D i use it to convert video files to flv :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test it in a local VM. Memory usage is more or less independent of file sizes (especially on the size of the program files), instead it depends on how it's used (number of concurrent connections, database queries, RAM usage per user of your PHP scripts etc.).